# Exclude results from Subsites from SP Rest API Search

Tags: search, sub-site, sharepoint-rest-api

I m useing the SP Search API to get results from a subsite with
http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='test path:http://localhost/subsite
works fine , but it also returns the results of the sub-subsites like http://localhost/subsite/website . 
How do I have to modify the url to exclude the sub-subsites from the search ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not.

Search searches everywhere it is allowed to search (index)

If you don't want things from subsites in the index you need to exclude them from being indexed in site settings or library settings

Answer (score 0):

I found a soloution . 
you can use WebId= instead of path:

for example:

```
http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='test+WebId="5c11e9b9-3182-444e-a2d4-c04db13c474f"
```